# I'm applying a border to an element while using box-sizing: border-box, but the border still adds up to the element's size

Tags: html, css

I've built a table using a separate grid for each row, now trying to add a border to it, but the border seems to add to the grid's size and thus shifts the content to the right, which i don't want, i want the content to remain static. [Picture illustrating what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwnxD.png).

I thought `box-sizing: border-box` would solve this problem, but the behaviour is still the same when i apply it.

I found a possible solution, which is to use `box-shadow` to emulate border, which works, but unfortunately it conflicts with existing borders in a way, where borders would stand out on top of the box shadow which creates a small but noticeable inconsistency in the design, so I want to figure out how to make borders work in this case.
Simplified HTML:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

.grid-wrap-3 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 85px 260px 180px 120px 159px 240px 240px 100px 65px 65px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 90px auto;
  gap: 4px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  transition: box-shadow .1s;
}

.border-selected {
  /*    box-shadow: 3px 0 0 #1f7a7a inset !important; */
  border-left: 8px solid #1f7a7a;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrap-3 border-selected" id="cell2">
  <div class="flex-center">
    <img id="square2" class="icon-square-check" src="assets\icons\square-check-regular.svg" onclick="squareChange(this)">
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="name">Abramov Andrey</h2>
    <p class="undertext">163</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3 class="small-text position">Product manager</h3>
    <p class="undertext">3 years</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-center team-text-shift">
    <h3 class="small-text">10</h3>
  </div>
  ........ some other
  <div>'s
  </div>
```

Comment: Add a transparent border in all of them and then change the border-color to green when needed.

Comment: That would work I think, however I got some other stuff above precisely lined up with the dimensions of the rows, so I would have to change all the dimensions of that too if I were to go this way. So I'd like to know if there any other solutions still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to 'save space' for the green line within the element itself - that is, you don't want the first element (the image) in the element to have to be positioned 8px in so that there is room for the green bar, then you could draw the green bar to the left of the whole element.

This snippet does this by adding a before pseudo element which is positioned absolutely to the left of the element by 8px, and because it is position absolute it does not alter the positioning of any other element.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

.grid-wrap-3 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 85px 260px 180px 120px 159px 240px 240px 100px 65px 65px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 90px auto;
  gap: 4px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  transition: box-shadow .1s;
  position: relative;
}

.border-selected::before {
  /*    box-shadow: 3px 0 0 #1f7a7a inset !important; */
  /*  border-left: 8px solid #1f7a7a; */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -8px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrap-3 border-selected" id="cell2">
  <div class="flex-center">
    <img id="square2" class="icon-square-check" src="assets\icons\square-check-regular.svg" onclick="squareChange(this)">
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="name">Abramov Andrey</h2>
    <p class="undertext">163</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3 class="small-text position">Product manager</h3>
    <p class="undertext">3 years</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-center team-text-shift">
    <h3 class="small-text">10</h3>
  </div>
  ........ some other
  <div>'s
  </div>
```